# Как в swagger передавать параметры в переиспользуемый компонент?

Tags: api, swagger, openapi

В успешном ответе каждого запроса повторяется данная структура:

```
status:
  type: string
message:
  nullable: true
  type: string
data:
  type: object
```

Хотел запихнуть ее в переиспользуемые компоненты, и инклюдить через $ref, однако есть одна проблема - структура в поле "data" в каждом ответе должна описываться по разному. Например в endpoint логина она возвращает api ключ и соответственно выглядит примерно так:

```
status:
  type: string
message:
  nullable: true
  type: string
data:
  type: object
  properties:
    api_token:    <-------
      type: string
```

Тогда как в endpoint для получения товаров картина иная:

```
status:
  type: string
message:
  nullable: true
  type: string
data:
  type: object
  properties: 
    product_id:    <-------
      type: string
    product_name:
      type: string
    product_count:
      type: integer
```

Вопрос: можно ли как-то в переиспользуемый компонент, на подобии параметров функции,  передавать куски спецификации, чтобы избежать данной проблемы?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете комбинировать и расширять определения моделей с помощью ключевого слова [`allOf`](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/oneof-anyof-allof-not/#allof).

Ваши модели можно представить так:

```
BasicAnswer:
  type: object
  properties:
    status:
      type: string
    message:
      nullable: true
      type: string

TokenAnswer:
  type: object
  allOf:
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/BasicAnswer'
    - type: object
      properties:
        data:
          type: object
          properties:
            api_token:
              type: string

ProductAnswer:
  type: object
  allOf:
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/BasicAnswer'
    - type: object
      properties:
        data:
          type: object
          properties:
            product_id:
              type: string
            product_name:
              type: string
            product_count:
              type: integer
```